# Storing entities with overlapping properties in MySQL and Doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to store a set of events in another entity. For this purpose, I have the following entities:

```
// Something that contains a load of events.
Something:
  id
  events

// An actual event.
Event:
  id
  timestamp
  eventname
```

Different events might be created, where different types have different properties. For example, the `key_down` event has a `binding` property, while the `damage` event has an `amount`. Previously I'd solved the problem in MySQL by having a table for each event type:

```
key_down:
  code
  binding

damage:
  target
  amount
```

And pointing `eventname` at the appropriate table:

```
id | timestamp | eventname
--------------------------
 1 | 2.5s      | key_down
 2 | 3.0s      | key_up
 3 | 7.4s      | key_down
 4 | 8.9s      | damage
```

My question is, what is the correct way of storing these in MySQL, and how does one represent this in Doctrine? In object-oriented design I would have stored the events as subclasses of `Event`.

Comment: With Symfony2 when you do like you would have (key_down & damage as subclasses of event) and then run the command to generate/update the schema, Doctrine will automatically create the corresponding tables.

Comment: doctrine2 supports various kind of Inheritance Mapping, [take a look at the doc here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).  Every approach have pro and cons, read the consideration for each one. Hope this help.

Comment: It might be useful to have Event and Property entities in a ManyToMany relationship.  A nice feature of Doctrine is that one need not create an entity for the intermediate table linking the two.  Inheritance mapping may become cumbersome as the number of properties increases.

Comment: I should clarify that the database is designed for an external application, not the website. So generating the table from the Doctrine schema is not desirable.

Comment: @Matteo Class Table inheritance seems to match my existing schema, and does what I want. However, I don't understand how one uses the resulting entities. If an object has a list of $events, for instance, how do I get the events that are KeyDown objects, or cast $events[0] to that (i.e. to access its attributes)? This seems too obscenely obvious to ask another question.

Comment: Hi @Druckles I understand, this approach have much limitations, sometime I resolve using the `INSTANCE OF` query condition for setting the appropriate entity type. I suppose you already see [this doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#query-the-type)