# Get subclass from repository using Class Table Inheritance

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I have one entity, say Person, which contains a list of `$pets`:

```
protected $pets;

public function getPets()
{
  return $this->pets;
}
```

Standard Doctrine. Unfortunately, these pets may be of different types, such as cats or dogs, or a mix. So I used Class Table Inheritance:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="pets")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="pettype", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"cat_animal" = "CatAnimal", "dog_animal" = "DogAnimal"})
 */
class Pet
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="eventid", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   */
  private $id; // protected did not work either

  /**
   * Get id
   */
  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->id;
  }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="cat_animal")
 */
class CatAnimal extends Pet
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="float")
   */
  protected $height;

  // etc.
}

// DogAnimal class omitted.
```

This was relatively straightforward using [Doctrine's docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

If I want to get all cats for an individual person, I have discovered I can do this:

```
public function getCats($person)
{
  return $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('MyBundle:CatAnimal')
    ->findByPerson($person);
}
```

However, how do I access the subclasses using a query builder? If I have the Person repository ($repos here), I want to do something like the following:

```
$repos->createQueryBuilder('person')
  ->select('pet.height')
  ->join('person.pets', 'pet')
  ->where('person = :person')
  ->setParameter('person', $person);
```

Except Pet doesn't have height, so this throws an exception. The DQL generated automagically joins to DogAnimal and CatAnimal, so I should be able to access these properties, but I don't know how. I have tried:

```
$repos->createQueryBuilder('person')
  ->select('cat.height')
  ->from('MyBundle:CatAnimal', 'cat)
  ->join('person.pets', 'pet')
  ->where('person = :person')
  ->setParameter('person', $person);
```

But this seems to do the cartesian product. I can solve that by adding:

```
->andWhere('person.id = cat.person')
```

This seems overly complicated for what I want. I have tried looking for the correct way to do this, but resources are limited.

This builds on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742715/storing-entities-with-overlapping-properties-in-mysql-and-doctrine), with a similar structure. The names of the tables were changed for clarity and generalisability.

Comment: Do you want to select all your CatAnimals owned by one person by QueryBuilder?

Comment: @Andrey Yeah, pretty much. In such a way that I can perform more queries on it. I believe Jean's answer is what I'm looking for.

Comment: The DQL generated by the query builder automatically joins with the subclasses in any repository. The question should be, how does one alias, or get the existing aliases of the subclasses using the query builder? To clarify, while both cat and dog are joined to pet, one cannot use 'height', or 'cat.height' in the query builder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join correctly to `Person`, adding a field to the `Pet` class. In  my example I named it `owner`:

```
$catRepo->createQueryBuilder('cat')
  ->select('cat.height')
  ->from('MyBundle:CatAnimal', 'cat')
  ->join('cat.owner', 'person')
  ->where('person = :person')
  ->setParameter('person', $person);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this from the person/owner repository?

Comment: Sure, you should just reverse the join.
But it would be conceptually wrong, you should get data about a Person from the PersonRepository.

Comment: That is data about the person: which cats belong to that person.

Comment: If you want to get a collection of Cats entities, that's something that should be returned by the Cat Repository. Or you could create a getPets method on the Person entity.

Comment: I've been told that's bad practice as well. My impression of Doctrine 2 so far is a lot of rules that make many things harder to do. Thank you anyway.

Comment: That's not a bad practice. It's bad to add logic into an entity's method, but that would be a simple relation mapping. I'll expand my code later with an edit

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I already have a getPets() method on the Person. What I need is getCats() (which obviously contains logic). Perhaps that should be done from the Cats repository. However, I want to get a bunch of information about one person, most of which is contained in various subclass objects. E.g. the number of cats they have, or the average height of the dogs they have. To do that, I use a separate class (PersonStatistics) which aggregates all that. However, I don't want to pass a repository for every animal that I want information about. So I've ended up passing Pets repos.

Comment: Oh ok great.
You could then implement a specific method on the PetsRepo that would return an array grouped by Pet Type